# How to Integrate ChatBot on an existing WordPress website?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, content-management-system

I am tying to integrate my ChatBot in my existing wordpress website. The ChatBot created using Vite React JS and I have dist folder, public folder. For now I wrapped my Wordpress site in React JS code using iframe but now I want to integrate my ChatBot in WordPress. Below I pasted two linke. The original WordPress webiste and a wrapped WordPress webiste. You can see in the last link I wrapped the whole WordPress website in React JS and you can see a ChatBot. The same ChatBot I want to implement in my official WordPress website.

I use ReactPress plugin to integrate my ChatBot but I didn't know how to use this plugin and which steps should I follow. Also I try to add my react js code in a WordPress theme but nothing works. Please help me to integrate my CHatBot in a WordPress website.

Here is the link of my Wordpress Website:
https://solutyics.com/

Here is the link of my wrapped WordPress website in React JS:
https://cb.solutyics.com/

Answer (score -1):

To integrate your ChatBot into your existing WordPress website, you have a few options. Since your ChatBot is built using Vite React JS, you'll need to ensure that it can be embedded within a WordPress environment. Here are some steps you can follow:

ReactPress Plugin:
Since you mentioned using the ReactPress plugin, this could be a viable option. However, if you're having trouble figuring out how to use it, you may need to consult the plugin's documentation or support resources. Typically, plugins like ReactPress provide shortcodes or other methods to embed React components into WordPress pages or posts. You would need to generate a shortcode for your ChatBot component and then insert it into the desired pages or posts on your WordPress site.